# Finding eigenvalues and basis for linear transformation $T: P_{100} \to P_{100}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $T: P_{100} \to P_{100}$ given by

> $ T(p(t)) = p(t) + p(2-t) $

Find all eigenvalues and a basis for each eigenspace of T.

So a standard basis for the $P_{100}$ is  {$1,t,t^2,t^3,...,t^{100}$}

$T(1) = 1 + 1 = 2$

$T(t) = t + (2-t) = 2$

$T(t^2) = t^2 + (2-t)^2 = 2t^2-4t+4$

So the matrix of transformation is going to look something like this
\begin{pmatrix}
     2 & 2 & 4 & 8 & \cdots \\
     0 & 0 &-4 & 12 &\cdots \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots     
     \end{pmatrix}

And I don't know where to go next.  can someone help me?

Comment: You could work through trying to solve the characteristic polynomial of this matrix, I suppose, but I suspect that the reason they’re having you work with such large polynomials is to encourage you to go the basic definition of eigenvector/eigenvalue: $T(p)=\lambda p$. That is, the eigenvectors of $T$ are those polynomials for which $p(t)+p(2-t)=\lambda p(t)$ for some $\lambda$. This has to hold for *all* values of $t$, which I think should seriously constrain what $p(t)$ could be.

Comment: Note that $T(T(p))=2T(p)$. So what can the eigenvalues be?

Comment: so somewhere out  there exists a $\lambda $  that I can multiply the polynomial to and that would be the same as $T(p)$?

Comment: Would the eigenvalue be 2 and 0 then?

Comment: Well 0 is the trivial case so just 2?

Comment: The $0$ vector is trivial, but there are other polynomials such that $Tp=0\cdot p = 0$.

Comment: I just noticed that it would be an upper triangular matrix?  Would this information help by any chance?

Comment: Here's a hint. A better basis to use for $P_{100}$ for this transformation is $(t-1)^0,(t-1)^1,(t-1)^2,\dots$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Show that $T^2=2T$. This greatly reduces the eigenvalues.

Second hint: A better basis to use is $1,t-1,(t-1)^2,\dots,(t-1)^{100}$.

Comment: Ok so I found that the eigenvalues are 0 and 2.  Now I just find the basis for each of them and I'll be done correct?