# Basis for the kernel and range of P3 for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $T$ : $P_3$ → $P_3$ be deﬁned by $T(p(t)) = p(t) + p(2−t)$.

Find a basis for the kernel and the range of T.

All i can think of is setting $T(p(t)) = 0$ so that $p(t)=-p(2-t)$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: That's a good start. Now write out a general cubic polynomial and see what that would mean for the coefficients.

Comment: That’s a good start. This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252275/finding-eigenvalues-and-basis-for-linear-transformation-t-p-100-to-p-100/2252299#2252299, but the dimension of the space is much smaller so that grinding through the solution directly isn’t too bad.

Comment: @Ken Duna When I did that, I ended up with $2t^3+2t^2(-3a+b)-4t(3a-b)+2(4a+2b+c+d)$=0. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Set the coefficients equal to $0$ and solve the ensuing system of equations.

Comment: @Ken Duna Okay =, a=0, b=0, and c=d. How do I say this in polynomial form? Sorry, I have only dealt with these types of problems in matrix form.